# some apps didn't response dispatchGesture sent by android AccessibilityService

Tags: android, appium

```java
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(595, 1847);
    GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
    gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, 100));
    dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), null, null);
```

I am using this code  to create simulated click events in accessibility services, but my target app seems to be able to distinguish such virtual click events and then do not respond.
Specifically:

I can use a hand click to trigger the click event of the corresponding button, while the simulated click does not work.

The code that simulates the click can be executed on another app.
I also tried adb shell input tap , it didn't work also.

But airtest can.

Is there any way to solve this problem (not root)? Or how does the bottom layer of the airtest do it? Can I directly invoke it in the AccessibilityService?

How can I send a recognized click to the target application,No root required.